# Google Sheet - Cut and Paste a cell into another cell (which is on another sheet)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need help on Google Sheet.
I want to fill the B column of my "Data" sheet by filling a cell in the "Interface" sheet. I made a script but it needs a while loop in order to write in empty cell. (my objective is to create a waiting list for customers)

My function will trigger when any change is done on the sheet. (i made some restriction on the sheet in order to only let people touch the 4 square (development in progress)

```
function Bouton1() {

  //the current sheet
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  //focus on B5
  spreadsheet.getRange('B5').activate();

  //go on Data
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Data'), true);
  //focus on B2
  spreadsheet.getRange('B2').activate();

  //copy
  spreadsheet.getRange('Interface!B5').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);

  //go on interface
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Interface'), true);

  //clean B5 
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
};
```

here my GSheet

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qksTPQTyUZCxxRFuQv9BP5UPtmNvyre4_MJKhrKM8ys

Comment: Try sharing your sheet again.  I can't access it.

Comment: ok wait a minute, done

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a log of what was entered anywhere (in those 4 cells) you don't need a loop

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Data");
  var newRow = Math.max(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 2);
  sheet.getRange(newRow, 2).setValue(e.value);
  e.range.copyFormatToRange(sheet, 2, 2, newRow, newRow);
  e.range.clear({contentsOnly: true});
}
```

Comment: with your script it only works on B5, how can I do for the cells B5 & B7 and clear the content only ?
i tried this but it deletes anything who is not in column B
  ss.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});

Comment: how can i copy the format too in order to know which name came from the interface sheet

Comment: Take a look at the updated response, this is now taking advantage of the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) that onEdit functions get passed implicitly.

Comment: Thanks but there is a weird problem. The first word is in cell B2 but the format is in B1